# Repeated flickering on fresh ubuntu 16 install attempt

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, flicker

I got a new laptop and was attempting to try the live distro version first before installing ubuntu.

However, when it loaded to the purple ubuntu loading screen:
[image]

The 5 dots turned red once, then the screen started flickering on and off with all the dots white except for the first.

Nothing else happens except the repeated flickering (and what seems to be it just repeating the same thing)

I can't get past this stage, no keyboard or whatever is working.

Some solutions I found on here seem to address the problem when ubuntu is already installed, not when its like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using:
i7 7700hq
nvidia gtx 1060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. *disappears*

..Just kidding. The solution was to disable UEFI in BIOS. *Not just secure boot but disable uefi loading as well*!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. When booting the live CD, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> when you see the two white icons at the bottom, one looks like a keyboard, one like a person.
2. Select your language if it comes up.
3. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to open **Other Options**.
4. Select `nomodeset` by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot.

That should prevent any graphical issues related the Nvidia cards during install. I've had similar issues like that myself.

Comment: hey, I dont get what you mean. when i load the comp, i get the black screen with the following: try ubuntu before install, install ubuntu, oem install, check disc for errors. pressing esc goes to grub